# What is this streaky Cyanotype artifact?

Tags: artifacts, cyanotype

So I made some cyanotype prints for the first time.

> So much fun !!! :D

However I seemed to be getting some artifacts in my highlights

See around the ship:

[image: Cyanotype print with artifacts]

Original to compare:

[image: The original]

So after exposing in the sun and starting to wash the print I noticed the artifact. It looked similar to what you see in the photo, but it was a pale violet color. As the print dried, most of it faded, then some turned yellow (kinda like the unexposed chems) then later turned into the blue colored artifact you see in the photo now.

**What is causing this artifact, and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Looks like you got the same thing on the left part, around the dark water area. I don't know much about cyanotype, but could that be brush marks?

Comment: @jhamon Perhaps. Although before exposing, it was 'evenly brush stroky'; and only some parts of the highlights (and mid tones) have the artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing brush strokes all over:

[image]

If the paper is textured, try alternating vertical and horizontal brush strokes. Possibly try a foam brush with more emulsion on it.

If the paper is smooth, try smoothing out the emulsion using a glass rod instead.